# Checking if integer is in list with bisect, list too big for memory

Tags: python, memory, lookup

I have a problem with a big look-up table that is too big for my memory:

I load a Python list from a numpy.save file, in which each element is an mpz(integer) from the module gmpy2. The integers are very big and all over the place, therefore I have to use this datatype.
My code repeatedly checks if a specific integer is in the sorted list with bisect. Only if it is not in the list, then I need to do an expensive computation.

This Python list is pretty huge, nevertheless this big look-up list makes my code run faster. I think I could have my code run even faster if I could  increase the list (the additional search time would still be small compared to the otherwise expensive computation).

My problem is, however, that the list is already maxing out my 8 GB memory.
What other options do I have? Is there a way I can have a look-up table by only partially storing the storing list in the memory and accessing the rest from the SSD? This would probably make the look-up a bit slower, but maybe I can still save time overall.

Any other ideas? I am running Windows 10, if that is important. Thanks!

Comment: You could use a database such as SQLite.

Comment: Unfortunately I get "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER"

Comment: just check if python int value is more than 2**32 or not, if yes then search how to save integer more then 32 bit in sqlite

Comment: I can only find how to store 64bit integers. I need 256bit

Comment: What data does the expensive computation use exactly? Does it need to use the lookup list?

Comment: The lookup list helps to avoid the expensive computation. If the integer is in the list, then I  can do a different, much simpler computation. Unfortunately there is no pattern underlying these special integers.

Comment: You don't need to do arithmetic, correct? Just check for existence? Try a `BLOB`.

Comment: That's what databases are for. With proper caching and the database stored on an SSD, you should be able to get your performance boost without using all your memory space.  Also, the 8GB limit of your physical memory can be extended on to virtual memory with larger page pools (wich I thought was automatic in W10).